# Send message to particular contact through WhatsApp in android

Tags: android, text, share, whatsapp

I tried so many solution but still no success in sending messages to particular whatsapp contact in my app. Here is my code :

```
  Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey");
                sendIntent.putExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(smsNumber) + "@s.whatsapp.net"); 
                sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                mContext.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

It is just opening particular contact chat window as new conversation with no contact name, profile pic and old conversion.

Please help me to solve this. Also attaching screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want like this.

```
private void openWhatsApp() {
        String text = message.getText().toString();
        if(whatsappInstalledOrNot("com.whatsapp")){
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("whatsapp://send?text="+text+"&phone="+mobileNumber.getText().toString()));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
private boolean whatsappInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        boolean app_installed = false;
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            app_installed = true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            app_installed = false;
        }
        return app_installed;
    }
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Readability note: `whatsappInstalledOrNot()` should be more properly named `isWhatsappInstalled`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @Amrish Kakadiya I tried and found that its only accepting number with country code also its taking time to search particular contact in whatsapp contact list.

Comment: Yes, It accepts only with country code. And thing about time, is about your internet. I think there is no other way to solve your problem. I have also searched many sites and questions about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp","com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey");
        sendIntent.putExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators("91xxxx008686")+"@s.whatsapp.net");
//phone number without "+" prefix (countrycode & contact number without '+')

        startActivity(sendIntent);
```

You have missed the set component part which retrieves old conversation from 'Conversation' class.